# Facebook login acting up in Windows Phone 7

Tags: wpf, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying out a "login with facebook" feature for a Windows Phone app. I have a very small prototype with a button and a webbrowser on a page. Clicking on the button directs the browser to a URL specified by the Facebook API in order to authorize an app with the details of the currently logged in user.

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Clic</Button>

        <phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" x:Name="webBrowser" Navigated="WebBrowser_OnNavigated"/>
    </Grid>
```

The code behind looks like so :

```
    private const string AppId = "123456"; // In my code I've put the correct App ID.

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + AppId + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(@"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")));
    }

    private void WebBrowser_OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.Uri.ToString();
    } // BreakPoint set here to inspect 'x'
```

This exact piece of code placed in a WPF application works as expected. That is, if I haven't authorized the app yet, the first hit on the 'OnNavigated' event handler reflects the URL above and then, after authorization, has a URL containing an authorization token. Here's the URLs and steps when I run it as a WPF app :

A. Start the app, clic the button :

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

Now I get presented with the "[your_app_name] will receive the following information about you : public profile and friends list". I click OK.

B. I am getting redirected to :

=">https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?code=AQAOJ7H6lK7dsRCJPRjVRVPZmxQrZ7ksWyqb87MfagEc1eatw_1n4ijY0IpDmbVQEg6Un3nmrvzhiiynM4S_l5S_ChgD7ZOVSf-JvxyD8S5sCHFUtBZ9H8lCrT0Lh7aRDgKW1u1XbWuUfcbXl2i6FndWG9Svk9bssRq7F4O-XrPsnK--b31qrFLptzrA0saC1stWoMhyR9vXkiLevxADQ7GHpeGQeu29mOhIaXWBtJy1Wlvins346kNR8Pi77wwpwAt5BzYsTRXdbYxbFdAPDJI2RJyqv4IMKGR0BucmtX9lrmBWcfJeMLzMag-GNDJ5I4U#*=*

(I've changed a few characters in the token above in order to protect my privacy)

---

Now this is great and it's what I need. I'll take the very same code and place it in a Windows Phone 7.1 app and the behavior changes like so :

First the URL differs, probably because it detects a mobile (touch) device :

A. Click the button :

https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=123456&signed_next=1&next=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html&client_id=123456&ret=login&cancel_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied%23_=_&display=touch&_rdr

Now I'm getting to the login page so I first login into facebook. I hit login.

B. I am getting to :

rdr#=_">https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_id=123456&ret=login&ext=1391596741&hash=AeYEMbLJMwI3QhOE&refsrc=https://m.facebook.com/login.php&refid=9&m_sess=c2VzczoxMDAwMDAwOTg1MjE5NzM6MzM6Ti13TjN3eUERd3ZrR1E6MjoxMzkxNTkzMTQxOjMwODE&*rdr#*=_

At this page I am getting asked if I want to authorize the app. I click OK.

**C. I get redirected to https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/read (no other querystring).**
*This is my issue*

---

**At this point I'm stumped since I have no auth token**. A workaround is to try redirecting the browser again to the first URL (see ButtonBase_OnClick) and that will work.

That means changing the OnNavigated event handler to :

```
    private void WebBrowser_OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.Uri.ToString();

        if (x == @"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/read")
        {
            ButtonBase_OnClick(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }
```

But that requires ANOTHER request and it definetely feels like a hack.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the app not configured properly?

Comment: Maybe it's just shoot in the dark - but can you try to enable scripts in your webbrowser Webbrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
(AFAIK by default switched off). Maybe it will help

Comment: did you try using different redirect URL? your server, or even localhost:43281 (need to have a thread  listening for the request on port 43281 though)? EDIT - port is just random number of course, only for illustration purposes.

Comment: No, I haven't tried using a different URL because on the facebook developer's site clearly says that for a desktop/mobile app you need to provide exactly that URL as a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the old method Use this:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/, And this is also a very simple method it will take you around 1-2 hours to setup.
And I am using it in my app and it is working great for me I am registering the user through this in my app and storing all the details.

Comment: does this solution require the end user of the app to have the Microsoft Facebook app installed on the device?

Comment: Nope.
You can see in my App i have used it:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/intube/2a1dcb8e-00be-4c59-b035-9124dfee81ae
on the Video Playing i have used sharing button in which i am sharing on facebook.

Comment: I've studied the scrumptious sample. It's based on an alpha version of Facebook.Client which is not even in Beta yet. It's still in alpha and you can't easily install from NuGet yet. This is, in my opinion, not a standard way, yet.

Comment: Its upto you i am using this method and its working good i know its in alpha but if its working good and in NuGet all the references are Trusted.

Comment: I got it to run on Windows Phone 8 (on device, my main PC does not have SLAT / HyperV support) but I can't get it to work with Windows Phone 7.1

Answer (score 1):

I had these working for my WP7.5 app which worked in WP8 too. It was using graph api before this Facebook SDk for .Net was born.

```
string strLoginURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=touch&scope=publish_stream,user_hometown";
string strAppID = "123456789101112";
string strPostMessageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/yourpageid/feed";
    string strAccessToken = String.Empty;

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format(strLoginURL, strAppID), UriKind.Absolute));
}

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string strSourceString = objAuthorizeBrowserControl.Source.ToString();
    //string strSourceString = e.Uri.OriginalString.ToLower();

    if (strSourceString.Contains("access_token"))
    {
            int index1 = strSourceString.IndexOf("access_token");
            int index2 = strSourceString.IndexOf("expires_in");
            strAccessToken = strSourceString.Substring(index1 + 13, index2 - (index1 + 14));    
    }
    /*...
    else
        logging in and authorize app will get redirected automatically untill access token is generated.
    ...*/

    if(strAccessToken != String.Empty)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string strParametersToPost = "access_token=" + strAccessToken + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourcontenttopost); 
        wc.UploadStringAsync(strPostMessageURL, "POST", strParametersToPost);
        // you can use wc.UploadStringCompleted Event to capture the result.
    }
}

private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    string strSourceString = objAuthorizeBrowserControl.Source.ToString();
    //string strSourceString = e.Uri.OriginalString.ToLower();

    if (strSourceString.Contains("access_token"))
    {
        int index1 = strSourceString.IndexOf("access_token");
        int index2 = strSourceString.IndexOf("expires_in");
        strAccessToken = strSourceString.Substring(index1 + 13, index2 - (index1 + 14));
    }
}
```

Comment: While using this graph api, there would be many navigation taking place within the web browser. The idea is to catch the access token whenever the url is contained with it.